# Reverse repeating linear gradient

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients, gradientstop

I'm using this piece of code to create a somewhat dotted border:

#### CSS

```
.strip {
    height: 5px;
    width: 80px;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent 10px, #ffaacd 5px, #ffaacd 30px);
}
```

I'm trying to reverse the colors by switching `transparent` and `#ffaacd` and their corresponding lengths but it doesn't work. I would get a straight pink line.

#### Note

Please note that I cannot use `border` because it affects some layout so I'd rather just use the background.

#### Edit

I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhfrra67/4/) to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Basically I'm doing some form of legend and right now the strip is starting with a transparent color but I want it to start with the pink color so that it is aligned with the strip above it.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle the reproduces the issue?

Comment: @JacobGray https://jsfiddle.net/dhfrra67/

Comment: @PatrickGregorio I don't see a problem with just switching the colors: https://jsfiddle.net/dhfrra67/1/

Comment: @JonathanLam the one where he gets a solid pink border

Comment: @JacobGray Oops...

Comment: @JonathanLam yes simply switching them works but the length of the pink line should be longer than the transparent.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @JacobGray Simply switch the colors but keep the length of each color remain.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio switch the colors position?

Comment: @JacobGray Right now I have a strip that starts with a short transparent followed by a long pink. I want them to change that into a strip that starts with a long pink followed by a short transparent. I'm creating a legend of some sort.

Comment: @JacobGray I've added an `Edit` clause in my question please check it out. Hopefully that helps you understand my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your length offsets are a little strange. If you want hard stops, you should have the both the `#ffaacd` and the `transparent` sections have a color stop at 10px.

It works if you change it to:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent 20px, #ffaacd 20px, #ffaacd 30px);
```

This gives you a `transparent` section for 20px and then a `#ffaacd` section for 10px. This is the opposite of the original.

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhfrra67/3/) for a working example.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I did have to switch the colors but I'm fine with that. Yeah I didn't understand the offsets but with your answer I got a bit of an idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not what u directly asked for, I suggest you using CSS outline as it does exactly what u want (a dotted border that doesn't affect layout) and is much simpler:

```css
.elem {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 2px dotted hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem"></div>
```

Comment: Isn't this just like a border? I need the color to be on the body of the element not on the sides.

Comment: I've added an `Edit` clause in my question please check it out. Hopefully that helps you understand my situation.

Answer (score 0):

For getting inverse pattern you must swap colours only, not lengths.  Colour-stop value lengths should be in successive order, if smaller follows greater (like the `...transparent 10px, #ffaacd 5px...` in your snippet) later value is clamped to former (ie 10px in your case).

Some proof-of concept variation with sides:

```css
.strip {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent, transparent 1%, #ffaacd 1%, #ffaacd 6%), repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent 1%, #ffaacd 1%, #ffaacd 6%), repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent, transparent 1%, #ffaacd 1%, #ffaacd 6%), repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent 1%, #ffaacd 1%, #ffaacd 6%);
  background-size: 1000px 5px, 5px 1000px, 1000px 5px, 5px 1000px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-x, repeat-y;
  background-position: top center, center right, bottom center, center left;
}

.strip-inv {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #ffaacd, #ffaacd 1%, transparent 1%, transparent 6%), repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffaacd, #ffaacd 1%, transparent 1%, transparent 6%), repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #ffaacd, #ffaacd 1%, transparent 1%, transparent 6%), repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffaacd, #ffaacd 1%, transparent 1%, transparent 6%);
  background-size: 1000px 5px, 5px 1000px, 1000px 5px, 5px 1000px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-x, repeat-y;
  background-position: top center, center right, bottom center, center left;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="strip">resize me</textarea> <textarea class="strip-inv">resize me</textarea>
```